# java.lang.IllegalStateException ScrollingFragment.java:263 Can't access ViewModels from detached fragment

Tags: java, android

On closing the app while music is playing in the background and opening it again it crashes. When I comment out line 263 `**getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(MUSIC_LOADER_ID);** it doesn't crash. But I don't want to comment out this line.

I tried LoaderManager.getInstance(this).destroyLoader(MUSIC_LOADER_ID); or getSupportLoaderManager() instead since getLoaderManager is deprecated but still no win. Please help.

```
 nestedFragmentAdapter = new NestedFragmentAdapter(getContext(), songMainArrayList, recyclerView, Action);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(nestedFragmentAdapter);
        nestedFragmentAdapter.setScrollingClick(new ScrollingClick() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(int position) {
                playFromThisFragment(position, false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDeleteClick(int position) {
                new MyApplication(getContext()).getWritableDatabase().deleteSongFromPlaylist(Name, songMainArrayList.get(position).getID());
                nestedFragmentAdapter.delete(position);
            }
        });
        getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(MUSIC_LOADER_ID);
```

Under this part of the code...
`@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader loader, Cursor data) {```

Comment: If your fragment is detached when you're doing anything with it, you *already* have a memory leak. You should fix that first and ensure you aren't doing any work after a fragment is detached.